# creditCard.validateCardReturningError(&error) in stripe iOS integration

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, stripe-payments, swift2

I'm trying to integrate Stripe in an iOS app using swift. and I keep getting these error from that line: creditCard.validateCardReturningError(&error)
error 1:   '_' is not convertible to '() throws ->()'
error 2: <> is not convertible to 'BooleanType'

```
  var error: NSError?
    if (creditCard.validateCardReturningError(&error)){
        var stripeError: NSError!
        Stripe.createTokenWithCard(creditCard, completion: { (token, stripeError) -> Void in
            if (stripeError != nil){
                println("there is error");
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message that you're receiving, it sounds like you're working with the new Xcode 7 beta and thus the new release of Swift. One of the most interesting and controversial changes with this new release is that Apple has modified the way that error handling works. Effectively, Apple has now added first class exceptions to the Swift language through the ErrorType and the ability to mark at the type-level functions that can potentially throw an error in their execution. You can thus expect to start seeing functions with the following signature:

```
func foo() throws -> Bar
```

This signals that the function foo will either throw an exception or return an object of type Bar.

The way that you handle such functions is through three new keywords: do, try and catch (you are likely familiar with the try-catch idiom from many other popular language). Effectively, the aim is to wrap the block of possibly exceptional code in a do, to mark specific calls to functions that can throw exceptions with try and, finally, to use catch statements to indicate what should be done in the case of the occurrence of specific exceptions.

In your case, a modified version of the following should work:

```
do {
    try creditCard.validateCardReturningError()
    STPAPIClient.sharedClient().createTokenWithCard(
            creditCard,
            completion: { (token: STPToken?, stripeError: NSError?) -> Void in 
        self.createBackendChargeWithToken(token!, completion: completion)
    })
} catch {
    println("There was an error.")
}
```

Note that Stripe hasn't officially released a new version of the iOS SDK for the beta so there isn't much yet with respect to new exception types, but I would keep an eye out on the Github repo for any updates.

Anyway, for more information on new Swift error-handling, I highly recommend the blog post over at the Big Nerd Ranch: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/error-handling-in-swift-2/. Let me know if you have any further questions!

Comment: I would but I don't have enough reputation yet to do so. Question: are you familiar with implementing stripe?

Comment: :You are right. I just did. And about stripe, I was able to implement stripe to a project I'm working on. But implement stripe connect is kinda hard for me to understand through their website. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts @agentcoops

Comment: @ralph007: Connect can definitely be a bit tricky to get started with, especially when integrating with iOS. If you have a specific question ask it on here, but if you want more general and conversational help with integration I'd recommend getting in touch via https://support.stripe.com/email.